# Install packages in Alpine docker

Tags: linux, docker, dependencies, dockerfile, alpine-linux

How do I write Dockerfile commands to install the following in alpine docker image:

1. software-properties-common
2. openjdk-8-jdk
3. python3
4. nltk
5. Flask

Answer (score 262):

The equivalent of `apt` or `apt-get` in Alpine is `apk`

A typical Dockerfile will contain, for example:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache wget
```

> `--no-cache` is the equivalent to:
> `apk add wget && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*`

or, before the --no-cache option was available:

```
RUN apk update && apk add wget
```

Alpine `rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*` has the Debian equivalent `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.

See the [Alpine comparison with other distros](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Comparison_with_other_distros) for more details.

Comment: Recent versions of alpine also allow you to use the `--no-cache` option; using that option, no `/var/cache` files are created, and it will automatically run `update`. So the equivalent to your example would be `apk add --no-cache wget`

Comment: Also upvoted to compensate for the mysterious down vote :)

Comment: is apk update still required to update? or is it implied with apk add --no-cache?